# What's the better way to issue pull request when developing a new feature

Tags: git, github, git-flow

I'm wondering an better practice for pulling an request on a forked project.
(I'm new to `git-flow`)

The scenario is that I forked an project and want to create an new feature "Add a people model "

So I typed  `git flow feature start person`

Then added those features I want.

Now, I'm in `(feature/person)` branch

Should I push this branch to my github by `git push --set-upstream origin feature/person`

Or do the job after I've done the `git flow feature finish person` and then `git push --set-upstream origin feature`

Which one is better for collaborate on github ? or both are bad practice ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the upstream to implement your new feature?

If so, push your feature branch to github and selected that branch for a pull request.

On a side note `git flow feature finish person` will actually delete your feature branch so if you do use that command there's nothing to push to github.